# Web forms UserControls - LoadControl in pre-init or page_load?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, page-lifecycle

In the [MSDN page lifecycle reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) it states that the pre-init is used to "Create or re-create dynamic controls."

However, [elsewhere on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx), an example implies that a dynamic user control should be loaded in Page_Load

Is this a contradiction? Or is pre-init used only for standard aspx controls?

What have I missed :)

**Edit:**
Either way works, however, there is presumably some benefit of one approach over the other.

(WebUserControl1 is a UserControl with a simple label property, *SomeProperty*)

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    WebUserControl1 wc1 = LoadControl(@"~\WebUserControl1.ascx") as WebUserControl1;
    wc1.SomeProperty = "Hello World";
    Controls.Add(wc1);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl1 wc1 = LoadControl(@"~\WebUserControl1.ascx") as WebUserControl1;
    wc1.SomeProperty = "Hello World";
    Controls.Add(wc1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **it depends** on your custom control.  If your user control doesn't need anything to happen before page_load, then you can go ahead and add your control during page load, if you have code in your user control that executes at an earlier time, then you should add your control at an earlier stage as the MSDN article suggests.

Comment: Agreed, and specifically, although one can create (LoadControl) the control in OnPreInit, it can't be 'added' to anything (since other controls such as Form etc aren't guaranteed to be present). And since wouldn't necessarily want to keep the dynamic control as a member variable to the page (otherwise why the need to create it dynamically - exception being a collection I guess) hence the tendency to create the control later on in the lifecycle. Since the control will 'catch up' the missing lifecycle events, there should be no side effects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you trying to pass information to the user control?  If so you can pass the information to the user control in the page_load event from the parent page.

Comment: Properties can also be set on the control in PreInit. Possibly the difference would be related to viewstate tracking.